# QTextEdit instead of QStringList

Tags: qt, qt4

Hi i want to set QTextEdit in QTreeWidget Item. Can you please help on this.

```
    QStringList strings;
    strings << QString("Item %1").arg(i+1);
    QTreeWidgetItem *parent = new QTreeWidgetItem(strings);
    ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(parent);
```

Here setting QStringList instead I need QTextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple/quick mock-up of what you're looking for, try this:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* blankEdit = new QTreeWidgetItem();
blankEdit->setFlags(blankEdit->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(blankEdit);
ui->treeWidget->editItem(blankEdit);
```

This will give you a blank, editable item that will look like a line edit. You'll have to do some other work, but if you want something quick and dirty, this might be what you want over Model/Views.

Although, I will say that the Model/View approach is the more "professional" route, and as spraff said, I'd look into using a Model, View, and Delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the UI should allow you to edit the items in a multi-line fashion? You need to [use delegates](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-stardelegate.html) to handle painting.

Or do you want to extract the [lines](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#split-2) from the [plain text](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop)?

Comment: In tree widget I want to  show QTextEdit instead of any text. Where i can enter data

Comment: Delegates then. Read about [model-view-controller](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html) -- Qt is easiest when you extend it in a consistent fashion.